# Function series estimate

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a problem with this estimate (which is given in a book, but the context is not important for this issue): first of all for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ define 
$\langle x \rangle = \sqrt{1+x^2}$; then how can we prove that, for any $k\in {1,2,\ldots}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R},\, x\leq0$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\langle x-n\rangle^{-k-1}}\leq C\langle x \rangle ^{-k}$$

In fact, the original formulation of the inequality is

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(1+|x-n|)^{-k-1}}\leq C\langle x \rangle ^{-k}$$

but one could take advantage of the trivial estimates $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

$$\langle x \rangle\leq \left(1+|x|\right)\leq \sqrt{2} \langle x \rangle$$

It could also be useful this inequality due to Peetre: $\forall x,y,s \in \mathbb{R}$

$$\frac{\langle x \rangle ^{s}}{\langle y \rangle ^{s}}\leq2^{|s|}\langle x-y \rangle ^{|s|}$$

One of my attempts:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\langle x-n\rangle^{-k-1}}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\langle x-n\rangle^{-k}}{\langle x-n\rangle^{-1}}$$ and from Peetre's inequality for $k$ as above

$$\langle x-n \rangle ^{-k}\leq 2^{k}\langle x\rangle^{-k} \langle n \rangle ^{k}$$  but then I cannot control $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\langle n \rangle ^{k}}{\langle x-n \rangle ^k}$$

I can use the hypothesis $x\leq0$ in $$\langle x-n \rangle = \langle n-x \rangle$$ and also in the fact (for fixed $n$)
$$\sup_{x\leq0} \langle x-n \rangle ^{-k} = \langle n \rangle ^{-k}$$
but I think that there is a crucial exploit of this hypothesis hidden somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x\le0$, $1+|x-n|=1+n+|x|$ for all $n\ge0$. Let $f(t)=(1+t+|x|)^{-k-1}$. The $f$ is decreasing as a function of $t$ and
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(1+|x-n|)^{-k-1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)\le\int_0^\infty f(t)\,dt=\frac1k\,(1+|x|)^{-k}. 
$$